vs 2022 how to repair debugger
when i try to debug freshly created blazor webassembly project this error comes up i dont know what to do i  cant find repair tool for debugger (used dot net 8.0)

i watche youtube video and tried to in stall ssl certificate .certificate installed but problem dont go away

found answers  1)if you are using chrome or edge web browser you can change it to firefox developer edition 2)in tools  -> options->debugging->Genaral ->make a tick for enable javascript debugging for ASP.NET  3)try clean reinstall VS Studio if it can affrodable
